# If Statement that evaluates two conditionals if first is true?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

say I wanted the following code:

```
Sub X
    If TextBox1.Text = "Value" then 
    ' Do something
    ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "Value1" then
    ' Also do some other code
    End IF
 End Sub
```

How would I do this?

I would like the program to check something first, and if that is true then check something else, and if that is true, also execute that code.

Comment: It is not clear, your code above cannot be true for the first if and also for the else if

Comment: Just nest your if statements.

Comment: How is `TextBox1.Text` going to be equal to two different values?

Comment: @clcto It's just an example, my question is how would I get it to evaluate both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you looking for [AndAlso](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz.aspx)?

```
If TextBox1.Text = "Value" AndAlso TextBox2.Text = "Value1" Then
    ....
End If
```

The `AndAlso` operator performs a logical operation between the two sides of the expression. It evaluates the first condition and if this condition is false it stop further processing (without evaluating the second expression). Only if both conditions are true the code inside the if is executed. This behavior is called [short-circuiting evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

However, the code in your question cannot be evaluated as true in both conditions for the same TextBox1

Answer (score 1):

```
If condition1

then

 if condition2

then

     // do something

    end if

end if
```

If the example in your code is valid, equals value1 then equals value2, do you mean you want if either, because it cannot be both equal?

In this case you can use OR.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of else-if, do:

```
    If TextBox1.Text = "Value" then 
    ' Do something
    end if
    If TextBox1.Text = "Value1" then
    ' Also do some other code
    End IF
```

or:

```
    If TextBox1.Text = "Value" then 
    ' Do something
        If TextBox1.Text = "Value1" then
       ' Also do some other code
        End IF
    end if
```

Depending on whether you want to execute B only if A is also true.

Comment: The inner IF will never be true